# Awesomenauts won't run on Manjaro

Tags: libraries, games, manjaro

I'm using Manjaro, and when I try to launch Awesomenauts (a Steam game) from Steam, it does not launch. Steam shows that I'm playing it for a slight second, but then I go back to just being "Online" instead of being "Playing Awesomenauts".

When I try to launch it from terminal, I get this error.

```
error while loading shared libraries: libtheoradec.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, libtheoradec.so.1 is on my system in /usr/lib, as when I run

```
ls -l /usr/lib/libtheoradec*
```

I get

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 02.07.2013 01:07 /usr/lib/libtheoradec.so ->  libtheoradec.so.1.1.4*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     21 02.07.2013 01:07 /usr/lib/libtheoradec.so.1 -> libtheoradec.so.1.1.4*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 100664 02.07.2013 01:07 /usr/lib/libtheoradec.so.1.1.4*
```

I'm really not sure where to go next with this.

Comment: It's probably looking for a 32bit version of the library.

Comment: How do I install that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lib32-libtheora

```
pacman -S lib32-libtheora
```